# How do I register custom JDBC dialect in Rstudio?

Tags: r, jdbc, google-bigquery, sparklyr, rstudio-server

I'm trying to analyze bigquery data in Rstudio server running on a google dataproc cluster. However, due to the memory limitations of Rstudio, I intend to run queries on this data in sparklyr but I haven't had any success importing the data directly into the spark cluster from bigquery.

I'm using google's official JDBC connectivity driver:
[ODBC and JDBC drivers for BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/odbc-jdbc-drivers)

I also have the following software versions running:

- Google Dataproc: 2.0-Debian 10
- Sparklyr: Spark 3.2.1 Hadoop 3.2
- R version 4.2.1

I also had to replace the following spark jars with the versions being used by the JDBC connectivity driver above or added them where they were non-existent:

- failureaccess-1.0.1 was added
- protobuff-java-3.19.4 replaced 2.5.0
- guava 31.1-jre replaced 14.0.1

Below is my code using the spark_read_jdbc function to retrieve a dataset from big query

```
conStr <- "jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;ProjectId=xxxx;OAuthType=3;AllowLargeResults=1;"

spark_read_jdbc(sc = spkc,
                name = "events_220210",
                memory = FALSE,
                options = list(url = conStr,
                               driver = "com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.Driver",
                               user = "rstudio", 
                               password = "xxxxxx",
                               dbtable = "dataset.table"))
```

The table gets imported into the spark cluster but when I try to preview it, the following error message is received

```
ERROR sparklyr: Gateway (551) failed calling collect on sparklyr.Utils: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 4) (faucluster1-w-0.europe-west2-c.c.ga4-warehouse-342410.internal executor 2): java.sql.SQLDataException: [Simba][JDBC](10140) Error converting value to long.
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.exceptions.ExceptionConverter.toSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.utilities.conversion.TypeConverter.toLong(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SForwardResultSet.getLong(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$makeGetter$9(JdbcUtils.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$makeGetter$9$adapted(JdbcUtils.scala:445)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:759)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

When I try to import the data via an SQL query, e.g

```
SELECT date, name, age FROM dataset.tablename
```

I end up with a table looking like this:

| date | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| date | name | age |
| date | name | age |
| date | name | age |

I've read on several posts that the solution to this is to register custom JDBC dialect but I have no idea how to do this; what platform to do it on, or if it's possible to do it within Rstudio. Links to any materials that would help me solve this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: The issue may occur due to mismatch in versions of the Spark and the connector. Can you check whether the versions you are using are not mismatching and are compatible with each other?

Comment: I've ensured that the spark and scala versions of my cluster and the sparklyr application are the same. 3.1.3 and 2.12 respectively. I'm not sure I understand how you mean by versions of spark and the connector. Could you give me more clarification?